# jquery and html select

Tags: html, jquery, mask, inputmask

Доброго времени суток всем, столкнулся с такой проблемой есть одно поле ввода **input id="siF3"** и виподаюши список  **select id="country"** в списке несколько стран пре выборе страны на поле вода налогового номера должна ставлятца маска но код не работает алерт срабатывает  а маска нет.

*P.S. Библиотека jquery 3.1.1 подключена и маскинпут js тоже*

вот код

```js
  $("#country").on("change", function() {
    alert(this.value);
    if ($("#country").val() == "oe") {
      $("#siF3").mask("ATU-99999999");
    } else if (($("#country").val() == "de")) {
      $("#siF3").mask("DE-99999999");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://www.smartled-schweiz.ch/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.smartled-schweiz.ch/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<select id="country" class="strani">
  <option id="land1" value="oe">Österreich</option>
  <option id="land2" value="de">Deutschland</option>
  <option id="land3" value="belgien">Belgien</option>
  <option value="bulgarien">Bulgarien</option>
  <option value="danemark">Dänemark</option>
  <option value="estland">Estland</option>
  <option value="finnland">Finnland</option>
  <option value="frankreich">Frankreich</option>
  <option value="griechenland">Griechenland</option>
  <option value="irland">Irland</option>
  <option value="italien">Italien</option>
  <option value="kroatien">Kroatien</option>
  <option value="lettland">Lettland</option>
  <option value="litauen">Litauen</option>
  <option value="luxemburg">Luxemburg</option>
  <option value="malta">Malta</option>
  <option value="niederlande">Niederlande</option>
  <option value="polen">Polen</option>
  <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
  <option value="Rumanien">Rumänien</option>
  <option value="schweden">Schweden</option>
  <option value="slowakei">Slowakei</option>
  <option value="spanien">Spanien</option>
  <option value="tschechische">Tschechische Republik</option>
  <option value="ungarn">Ungarn</option>
  <option value="vereinigtes">Vereinigtes Königreich</option>
  <option value="zypern">Zypern</option>
</select>

<div>
  <input id="siF3" name="UID" size="20" style="width:100%;" value="" maxlength="30" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: "Библиотека jquery 3.1.1 подключена и маскинпут js тоже" - ну так вставьте их в Ваш код, соедините оба фрагмента в один и добавьте туда input

Comment: уже сделал но результат нулевой алерт работает а маска нет и чуть чуть изменил код но толку никакого.

$("#country option:selected").val() == "oe")

Comment: вставьте их в Ваш код **в вопросе**

Comment: может я выгляжу глупо но все поставлено все на странице прописано. =(

Comment: Подключите нужные файлы в сниппет, чтобы можно было попытаться воспроизвести вашу проблему прямо здесь.

Comment: я поправил Ваш код, осталось только воспользоваться предложением @br3t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле `mask` применяется, просто т.к. input без фокуса, то маски не видно. Если вам нужно её увидеть - принудительно добавляете фокус инпуту:

```
    $("#country").on("change", function() {
      alert(this.value);
      if ($("#country").val() == "oe") {
        $("#siF3").mask("ATU-99999999").focus();
      } else if (($("#country").val() == "de")) {
        $("#siF3").mask("DE-99999999").focus();
      }
    });
```

Comment: тут все работает но на сайте не работает маска, ладно буду решат вопрос спасибо всем...